# How to subtract from a single column in the MS SQL table which has dates in the MM/DD/YYYY

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, date, sql-update

I have a column in my MS SQL table called Effective_Date. In the Effective_date column, we have the dates in the MM/DD/YYYY format

Now I want to subtract 6 days from the dates in the Effective_Date Column.

For Example, I have a date of 5/22/2020 in the effective date column, I want to delete the 6 dates from 5/22/2020 to become 5/16/2020.

This should be applied for all the dates present in the Effective_date column of the table.

Comment: What is the datatype of column `effective_date`?

Comment: Please add sample data here, showing input and output after the delete query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that you want an `update` query, where 6 days should be substracted from `effective_date` on each row.

If `effective_date` is of a `date`-like datatype, you can just do:

```
update mytable 
set effective_date = dateadd(day, -6, effective_date);
```

If it's a string, then you would need to `cast` it to a `date` first, do the date arithmetics, then format it back to string:

```
update mytable 
set effective_date = format(dateadd(day, -6, cast(effective_date as date)), 'MM/dd/yyyy');
```

Comment: You are swapping the DD/MM order in this solution!!